# installing node lts with nvm on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, nvm

I've installed nvm on windows (from [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#node-version-manager-nvm-for-windows)), but running `nvm install lts` prints:

```
lts.0.0  
Node.js vlts.0.0 is only available in 32-bit.
```

How do I install node lts on windows?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

To install and use the latest LTS release of Node.js:

```sh
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
```

To install and use a specific LTS release of Node.js:

```sh
nvm install lts/erbium
nvm use lts/erbium
```

Comment: This is for the real version of nvm, not nvm-windows.

Comment: For windows: `nvm install lts`

Answer (score 21):

Following [this github comment](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17538#issue-351236897), just run `nvm list available` and then `nvm install x.y.z`

Don't forget to `nvm use x.y.z` after you're done. I used [this manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-windows) - in case it helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
nvm install --lts.14.15.4
```

Downloading node.js version 14.15.4 (64-bit)...
Complete

Answer (score 3):

Removing the prepended `--` from `lts` worked for me (instead of `nvm install --lts`):

```bash
nvm install lts
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it not working of nvm install --lts then try to below code is working

```
nvm install lts
```

Showing the list of package nodes is below

```
nvm list
```

Also, remove old npm package used

```
npm uninstall 18.16.0
```